# Problem with manual Change Tracking Cleanup

Tags: sql-server

I read [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/change-tracking-cleanup-part-2/) regarding the manual Change Tracking Cleanup stored procedure; however the manual clean up doesn’t look like working for me.

Here is my test set up:

- Created a test database and enabled change tracking with retention set to 5 min
- Created a test table and enabled change tracking on it and entered some test data, like 15000 rows
- Performed some random updates
- Checked the change tracking internal table and the change tracking meta data made it to the internal table as expected
- Waited for > 5 min and then executed `exec sp_flush_CT_internal_table_on_demand  @TableToClean = 'test_CTcleanup'` under DAC and with out DAC, but the older change tracking meta data doesn’t look like being cleaned up
- I have kept the change tracking auto clean disabled on the database, as I want to perform a manual clean up

Can someone please let me know where I am doing something  wrong?

Comment: The blog posts' stored procedure that was introduced in the CU/SP does not clean up all of the CDC tracking tables, just the side tables. This is known and I'd have to check to see if a fix was put out or not, recently, but the current work around is to enable auto cleanup as that's the only way to flush the main tracking tables, currently.